# Paypal payment integration selection

Tags: php, paypal

i have to integrate paypal payment gateway in php and iam in a state of confusion of selecting which method i have to choose.

I have gone through paypal developers documentation and found two methods.

1) REST API
2) Classic API

In classic apis there are still lot other options.

I have to build a website with payment feature for a client in US and no other country will be using this website.

So which option will be best suitable and on what scenario i have to select REST API and Classic API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PayPal Classic and REST API**

**Classic API**

- Request and response payloads are formatted as NVP and SOAP.
- Official PayPal SDK support for Express Checkout available with the
  PayPal Merchant SDK for .NET (GitHub | NuGet)

**REST API**

- Request and response payloads are formatted as JSON
- Official PayPal SDK support available with the PayPal .NET SDK
  (GitHub | NuGet)

The PayPal Name-Value Pair API (NVP API) enables you to leverage the functionality of the PayPal API by simply sending an HTTP request to PayPal and specifying request parameters using name-value pairs. The NVP API is a lightweight alternative to the PayPal SOAP API and provides access to the same set of functionality as the SOAP API.

> A few points to consider with respect to **Classic API vs. REST API**:

- Classic API is not going to be deprecated any time soon. You can use
  Classic API.
- Moreover REST API does not support many variables/parameters that
  work in Classic API.
- REST API can be used for both credit card and PayPal payments
  (express checkout architecture).

> **Note:** The REST Apis, they support both direct credit card and express
>   checkout depending on which funding instrument (CC vs PayPal) you pass
>   in the pay request.

Comment: if i do not want to redirect to paypal page and have to stay in same to for payment (something like iframe or javascript sdk). which options should be better.

Comment: You can refer developer sdk in link https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/

Comment: Why do  you call the NVP API a lightweight alternative to the SOAP API? Do you mean that the NVP API does not provide all the functionalities available in the SOAP API?